# listview and tab

Tags: android, windows

i want want to make an app that allows the navigatiton to another activity that have a tab control. This navigation is done  using the click event on a item. Can somebody help me with this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this would be possible using different activities, perhaps if you're looking to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) (which are similar to activites) you could combine several into a single app using some sort of tab interface.  However, my question would be why you would want to combine several activities into a single interface?

As for making a single activity using a tabbed view, I'd start with checking out the [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) class for the layout, and use a [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) object for the content portion inside each tab.  If you're looking for some example code to get you started, [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) is a great place to start.

Comment: well, i have already a listview with items. I want to see a description of this items on another view. I thought this view could have a two description of this item, separeted in two tabs. For instance, my item is a country and when i click in the country item that switch to another view that have two tabs, one with the population of the country and another about weather.

Comment: It's fine, that's what this site is about!  So what are you asking here?  a standard listView has an onItemClickListener that should override the onItemClick method.  If I were you, I would use that event to take me to the activity with the Tab View using the TabHost and TabWidget.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna do that. Can you instruct m about some sites that have a tutorial on how to this method? thanks

Comment: @fergol1985 Look at the code below and search on here for TabHost. Also review the SDK docs and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to create 1 tab using TabHost. You simply duplicate the code for each tab. You will also need some xml to define the tabs look. The XML below will switch images as it's selected.

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, your1TabClass.class);          
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Main").setIndicator("Name-of-tab",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.your-tab-xml))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

And Corresponding your-tab-xml.xml Layout

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/settings"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mountain" />
</selector>
```